# MySQL M-N Relationship with extra attributes and permissions

Tags: mysql

I have a task in which I have to represent a M-N Relationship between a Users table and a Courses one. The goal is to allow only some Users (with a level of privilege) to see some Courses details(other tables related). The things get complicated because a user can have multiple privilege levels on different courses. For example - attending Course1 will give him privilege 1, watching Course2 will give him privilege 2 and so on. I am thinking to have a table users_courses which will store the relationship between a user and a course and also the privilege level (e.g. for columns: UserID | CourseID | Privilege). 
The question is, can I create this join table including Privilege field ? 
Is there another simpler approach ?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach to me

Answer (score 3):

You can use RBAC pattern for that purpose. The picture below shows an example using **users, permisions, and applicationes**.  In your case you would be using **users, privileges and courses**. You can also use roles for a better privileges handling.

[image]

Comment: hello, can you be a bit more explicit with this approach/ which are advantages/disadvantages ?

Comment: I don't get it, it seem over complicated for nothing, what if instead of roles we have only identifiers so we escape one table ?

Comment: You can omit the table "Role" if you want. However, using this table you can group users by roles, it means that giving an specific privilege to a role you are giving the privilege to all users that have this role.